# Should I run multiple tor relay vms on one machine?

Tags: virtual-machine

I setted up a tor relay in a vm and set the number of cpu to four in the config.
Everything is working great.

My remaining question is: Should I copy this machine and run multiple instances? Would this help the network? If yes, how many should I run?

Answer (score 1):

If you will be able to put them in different C-class subnets on a static IPv4 addresses - then run as much as you need. Actually, you can set the cpu count to 2, it's ok because the crypto part in Tor is still single-thread

Comment: Why should I put them into different C-class subnets? And "as much as you need"? I don't need anyone, I try to help the network ;) Reither I asked myself home much makes sense.

Comment: Because IP's in one C-class subnet are very easy to ban and it will be better to have a different addresses. To help the network - the more the better :) Every node makes the network more diverse and capable of carrying a greater load

Comment: OK thanks! That makes sense!
I will run the other servers on Port 22, 110, and 143

Comment: Use 80 as DirPort, 443 as ORPort - or if you want to run a bridge I advice you to use 80 as DirPort, 443 as Obfs4 bridge port and 22 as ORPort

Comment: I already have a web server running on this port, otherwise I would have done this.

Comment: NGinx? if it's nginx - it's possible to address non-hosted requests to Tor 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: The Webserver runs on a different host and is not NGinx.